# Creating cognito Facebook identity provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito-facebook

I'm using boto3 on a lambda create a Facebook Identity Provider using:

```python
response = client.create_identity_provider(
    UserPoolId='us-east-2_asqweo3',
    ProviderName='MyAppProviderName',
    ProviderType='Facebook',
    ProviderDetails={
        'app_id': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'app_secret': 'xxxxxxxx'
    }
)
```

...but I'm getting an error saying

> Identity provider cannot be of type 'Facebook'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> ProviderName and ProviderType must have same value i.e. 'Facebook'

Also **ProviderDetails** for **Facebook** should be like

`"ProviderDetails": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxx",
        "authorize_scopes": "public_profile, email"
    }`

I know it's a late reply, but posting anyway for anyone who is facing this issue.